# how to pass two array variable to view page and the value from there in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am creating edit page. So in the form fields i want fetch data ffrom two tables.. so in controller am fetching data from each table to different array variable. and trying to pass those variable to the same view page.. and there tryingf to get one table data for fields and other to make dropdown list. but its showing **error**

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$groupID
>   (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\opennGTS\resources\views\vehicle\add.blade.php)

my controller page is giving below

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    try {
        //Find the vehicle object from model if it exists
        $grouplist = Map::select('groupID','description')->get();


        $devices = DB::table('device')->where('deviceID', '=', $id)->get();

        //Redirect to edit vehicle form with the user info found above.
        return view('vehicle.add')->with('devices', $devices)->with('grouplist',$grouplist);


    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $err) {
        //redirect to your error page
    }
}
```

and view page is

```
 @extends('app')

@section('content')
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">View/Edit Vehicle</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading">View/Edit Vehicle Information</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('vehicle/update/') }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
@foreach($devices as $device)
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vehicle ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deviceID" value="{{ ($device->deviceID)}}">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Creation date</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="creationTime" value="{{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',($device->creationTime))}}">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!--<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Server ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="" placeholder="Enter User ID">

                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Unique ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uniqueID" value="{{ ($device->uniqueID)}}" placeholder="Enter Unique ID">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Active</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ ($device->isActive) }}" name="isActive" >
                                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                            <option value="0">No</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vehicle Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ ($device->description) }}" placeholder="Enter the description">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="displayName" value="{{ ($device->displayName) }}" placeholder="Enter Display Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vehicle ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vehicleID" value="{{ ($device->vehicleID) }}" placeholder="Enter Vehicle ID">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">License Plate</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="licensePlate" value="{{ ($device->licensePlate) }}" placeholder="Enter license Plate">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">License Expiration</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="licenseExpire" value="{{ ($device->licenseExpire) }}" placeholder="Enter license Expire Date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Equipment Type</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="equipmentType" value="{{ ($device->equipmentType) }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Equipment Status</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ ($device->equipmentStatus) }}" name="equipmentStatus" >
                                            <option>Unspecified</option>
                                            <option value="inservice">In Service</option>
                                            <option value="rented">Rented</option>
                                            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                                            <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                                            <option value="available">Available</option>
                                            <option value="unavailable">Unavailable</option>
                                            <option value="repair">Repair</option>
                                            <option value="retired">Retired</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">IMEI/EDN Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="imeiNumber" value="{{ ($device->imeiNumber) }}" placeholder="Enter IMEI/EDN Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Serial Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="serialNumber" value="{{ ($device->serialNumber) }}" placeholder="Enter Serial Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!--    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Data Key</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SIM Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="simPhoneNumber" value="{{ ($device->simPhoneNumber) }}" placeholder="Enter SIM Phone Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SMS Email Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="smsEmail" value="{{ ($device->smsEmail) }}" placeholder="Enter SMS E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!--    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Group Pushpin ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Map Route Color</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ ($device->displayColor) }}" name="displayColor" >
                                            <option>Default</option>
                                            <option value="#000000">Black</option>
                                            <option value="#a52a2a">Brown</option>
                                            <option value="#dd0000">Red</option>
                                            <option value="#b37400">Orange</option>
                                            <option value="#008f00">Green</option>
                                            <option value="#0000ee">Blue</option>
                                            <option value="#9400d3">Purple</option>
                                            <option value="#505050">Grey</option>
                                            <option value="#00b3b3">Cyan</option>
                                            <option value="#ff1493">Pink</option>
                                            <option value="none">None</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>




                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fuel Capacity</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fuelCapacity" value="{{ ($device->fuelCapacity) }}" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Driver ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="driverID" value="{{ ($device->driverID) }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                         <!--       <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Reported Odometer</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Reported Engine Hours</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-15">
                                            <label class="control-label">Group Membership</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('groupID') }}" name="groupID" >
                                                @foreach( $grouplist as $group)
                                                    @if ($grouplist->groupID == old('description'))
                                                        <option value="{{ $group->groupID }}" selected>{{ $group->groupID.'['.$group->description.']' }}</option>
                                                    @else
                                                        <option value="{{ $group->groupID }}" >{{ $group->groupID.'['.$group->description.']' }}</option>
                                                    @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                            Update
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
@endforeach
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

any one please tell me how to do this and what wrong i had done in my code. Responses are appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside this foreach

`@foreach( $grouplist as $group)`

you are doing `$grouplist->groupID`

instead of `$group->groupID`

The exception you get is telling that `groupID` does not exist in the `Collection` class. In your loop, `$grouplist` is your Collection and `$group` is your item

Comment: oopz... Sorry. now i got it. Thanks dude... :) _/\_

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this way:

```
  return view('vehicle.add',[
          'devices'=>$devices,
          'groupList'=>$groupList
    ]);
```

But, you can use this:

```
    return view('vehicle.add')->with(['devices'=>$devices,'groupList'=>$groupList]);
```

Comment: where you are closing square bracket?

Comment: i got the answer, actually it was my mistake , while writing the code. Anyway thanks for your valuable response